# Exporting plotly as webpage offline without plotly JS included? (R ggplot2)

Tags: javascript, html, r, plotly, r-plotly

I know that to export plotly in python another stack-exchange post says:

```
plotly.offline.plot(data, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
```

Is there such a thing for R?

When I save as webpage it's a massive file full of javascript.

I want to use their javascript

```
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

and then have a small div id or whatever you call it.

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: I know it can be exported into HTML, but those HTML documents are massive (3 megabytes or more) because they contain the javascript. Is there a way to export them without the plotly javascript and then just use the CDN script above to call the javascript?

Comment: you can export it as html using `htmlwidgets`-Package with the function `saveWidget()`. But in my experience it doesn't behave well, therefore a way to save it as javascript seems intruiging to me

Comment: I know you can export as HTML, but the HTML document will be huge (over 3 megabytes in my attempts), due to containing the javascript inside of each HTML file. I want the file to only have the necessary HTML data, and then call the javascript from the CDN

Comment: Completely agree. That's why you got a +1 from me. Additionally I added html and javascript to the tags and removed the ggplot tag - Both should help to find answers. But likely this will be tumbleweed.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't see the tag changes on my end?

Comment: needs to be peer-reviewed....